# Open formula doesn't return name

Tags: reporting, pentaho

I have written open formula in **Pentaho Report Designer 5.0.1** as:

```
=SINGLEVALUEQUERY("SELECT name FROM income_product where order_no=1";)
```

Rather than writing a query on data set and call from `SINGLEVALUEQUERY()` I want the string value from the above query.

PRD doesn't complain about the above formula as syntax error; it just returns null/nothing.  What (if anything) is wrong in that formula?

I want to write that formula to generate dynamic column name for a report having order number 1 or greater.  Is there any other way to make the column name dynamic for a report?

By "Dynamic column name", I mean making different organization have unique `income_product_order`.
If I just assign the `order_no` of `income_product` it automatically gets `income_product_name` as the column name for all organizations.

Answer (score 0):

1. Did you set up your connection correctly? try adding a query over that connection and paste that query there. Does it return any data?

This is a good blog post on the subject: https://www.on-reporting.com/blog/using-queries-in-formulas-in-pentaho/

2. You can enable the "Display the index columns  (...)" option under Settings. It'll allow you to reference columns either by name or by index (column0, column1, etc.)

Comment: Answer No.1 was the solution that I'm currently using. I want to know another way if there is.

Ans No.2 I tried, but It gives the content of report instead of a column name.


Ouput : http://s1.postimg.org/5f9f0wban/reference_columns_by_index.jpg